# Take and save picture on button press

Tags: android, camera

I'm creating an Android application which uses user captured images as part of a larger process. So far my XML layout has a SurfaceView and Button inside a RelativeLayout. I've managed to get the camera preview to show on the SurfaceView but I'm stuck on how to take a picture and save it when a user presses the button.

My class file looks something like the CameraPreview API demo:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

Ideally, when the button it pressed the camera should autofocus, snap a picture (with the clicky sound), save it to `/data/data/app_package_structure/files/file_name.jpg`, then pop up a Toast to tell the user their image has been saved.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think CommonsWare has really already answered most of this question, but this might work for the auto focus and the shutter sound. This is a guess, since I'm not at a machine where I can compile/test any of this.

In your button-press-handling code, I believe you should call (possibly by message passing)

```
camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
  Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {
    public void onShutter() {
      // Play your sound here.
    }
  };
  public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, photoCallback);
  }
});
```

where `camera` is your camera object, and `photoCallback` is the same as in CommonsWare's example.

Exactly what is it that you are stuck on?

Oh, and don't forget to add the `<uses-feature>` tag `android.hardware.camera.autofocus`. :)

Comment: This is excellent help. My autofocus is working great now. I've just got one hurdle to get over, saving the picture. What is returned by takePicture(), what do I do with it in photoCallback and how do I save that result as an image?

Comment: Well, my guess is that `takePicture` returns nothing, instead the picture is passed as a JPEG format byte-array to photoCallback via its `onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)` callback method. You probably only have to write those bytes straight to file.

Comment: At least that was my impression from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PictureCallback.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29

Comment: The shutter sound should be in the shutterCallback that's passed into takePicture.  Thanks for the tip Mikael!

Answer (score 9):

[Here is a sample application](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture/) that handles the take-a-picture-and-save-it part. Auto-focus, clicky, `Toast`, and saving to the app-local file store vs. the SD card are left as exercises for the student. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that sameple (which I've already seen before) but I'm really looking for a more complete answer to my question.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  Just an update - I was looking at SurfaceHolder in the developer docs and it is stated that the method setType has been deprecated and so are the constants SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS, SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL, SURFACE_TYPE_HARDWARE and SURFACE_TYPE_GPU.

Comment: @Abhijit: They were deprecated as of Android 3.0. You need them for Android 1.x and 2.x. They can be skipped for Android 3.x and higher.

Comment: @Commons  i used same code and it works fine except in samsung galaxy s4.